# C Program Printing Duplicate Char

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a program in C that reads a word and prints if there are any duplicates and if so the number of occurrences. It works (as you can see in the attached pic) but once a letter has been printed I don't want it to reprint the same letter.

I've tried storing the duplicate chars in an array and then comparing the new duplicate to the duplicate array but it doesn't seem to be working.
Anyone know a simple way to not reprint?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
char word[100];
int x, i, j, freq, duplicates;
printf("Enter a word>\n");
scanf("%s", word);
x = strlen(word);
duplicates = 0;
freq = 1;
for(; i < x; i++) {
    j = 0;
    for(; j < x; j++) {
        if ((word[i] == word[j]) && (i != j)) {
                freq = freq + 1;
            }
    }
    if (freq >= 2) {
            printf("Duplicate letter: %c, Occurences: %d\n", word[i], freq);
            duplicates = 1;
            freq = 1;
        }
}
if (duplicates < 1) {
    printf("No duplicates found\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `i` is not initialised - change `for(; i < x; i++)` -> `for(i = 0; i < x; i++)`

Comment: you don't need to, it assumes i is 0 if you just write what I did.

Comment: Rubbish. That's undefined behaviour. Learn it now and learn it **well**.

Comment: why do you use for-loops and then leave out the initializer?  In the first loop, as Paul pointed out, not initializing `i` there causes problems since it is never initialized.  In the second loop, you initialize `j` before the loop instead of just putting it in the initializer that exists specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Always initialize variables explicitly.

Comment: So how come it runs without ever initialising it? (not arguing, curious)

Comment: @AngusRyan Undefined behavior can do anything.  It can fail horribly if you're lucky, but if you're unlucky, it might appear to work as you intend.

Comment: thanks, will be initialising e v e r y t h i n g from now on.

Comment: why do I get downvoted for trying to learn something I dont know? How is it a bad question if im the one who doesn't understand it?

Comment: @AngusRyan: not my down-vote, but some possible reasons *might* be: (i) no attempt at debugging, (ii) poorly formatted code, (iii) posting images of text instead of text, (iv) attitude in comments. Having said that, it's not a terrible question, and you only got one down-vote, so I wouldn't worry too much - just try and work on quality a little in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is in `for`s that look for the duplicate letter
The first one should go throw the string to look for all letters:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
```

The second should look for the occurrence of the same character:

```
for (j = i; j < x; j++) {
```

Comment: that won't work because if you have a word like aaapple it will state a occurs 3 times, then when you go back through the for loop it will say a occurs 2 times as it is ignoring every point before the array starts

Comment: @AngusRyan I would think of a table that stores duplicated letters, but, I think it will be a memory waste.

Answer (score 0):

Its because it runs once on each time it finds t and e respectively. One solution would be to find all occurrences of that char in the char array after printing the duplicate notification and removing it.

```
char * removeLetterFromArray(int toBeRemoved, char* string, int stringLength){
char * newString = malloc(stringLength * sizeof(char));

for(int i = 0; i < toBeRemoved; i++){
    newString[i] = string[i];
}

for(int i = toBeRemoved; i < stringLength; i++){
    newString[i] = string[i + 1];
}

return newString;
}
```

that code should remove the letter that you define the index of with toBeRemoved

So after you find a letter that has a duplicate loop through the code to find all places that letter occurs and pass them indexs to the above method.

If you do not wish to use the above method another option would be to create an array of letters that have already been output and ignore these letters in the future.